# Wordpress + Bootstrap

Tags: menus, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have integrated Bootstrap with Wordpress, and implemented [wp-bootstrap-navwalker](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) to build menus. Bootstrap and navwalker are working as you can see my project [here](http://www.andreimaxwel.com/).

The only problem is the CSS on the menu, I have tried a lot of stuff, but nothing seems to get it right. The levels of the menu doen't work correctly, the mobile verson too and the worst is that if I click "Blog", a JS removes the text information.

Anyone have sucessfully implemented Wordpress + wp-bootstrap-navwalker + CSS?

Thank you so much!

---

Thanks for your help, I was looking at my code structure, and it is organized like this:

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">...</nav>

<div id="page">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
           ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
           ...
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Where do you mean I should add `container` and a `.row` elements?

P.S.: My code is based on the examples inside bootstrap-3.3.1 package.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I've seen you're missing [bootstrap CSS grid markup](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) inside your page div,

so to start add `container` class to page div and below that a `.row` element,

for more inforamation on how the Bootstrap grid works check documantation and remember that all Js and styles are based on the correct markup selectors_

Comment: maioman, take a look at my code structure...

Comment: AFAIK the navbar needs container and <div id="page"> shouldn't be there..